# scroll position getting messy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made autoexpand textarea on keyup event in textarea but when it start growing outer div scroll came down on key press and goes up. Even when I scroll (down)bottom (outer div scroll) on key press in textarea it goes to the top (upward). How could i resolve this.

See the Following jsfiddle link.

```
$("textarea").on("keyup", function($event) {
    $(".parent").scrollTop($(".parent").prop("scrollHeight"));
var textarea = $event.currentTarget;
            if (textarea.scrollHeight > 305) {
                textarea.style.height = "100px";
                textarea.style.height = (3+textarea.scrollHeight)+"px";
                $(textarea).css("overflow-y","scroll");
                //$(".scrollablePanel").scrollTop($(".scrollablePanel").prop("scrollHeight"));
            }
            else if (textarea.scrollHeight > 105){
                $(textarea).css("overflow-y","hidden");
                textarea.style.height = "100px";
                textarea.style.height = (3+textarea.scrollHeight)+"px";
                //$(".scrollablePanel").scrollTop($(".scrollablePanel").prop("scrollHeight"));
                $('.scrollablePanel').scrollTop($('.scrollablePanel').scrollTop() + 14);
            }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ffzpa4qa/

Comment: and why do you need the scroll?

Comment: since in my app height of content is greater than height of div and if i dont add the scroll textarea will get hide when it will grow.